# Invoke Ripple Emulator from chrome with our custom web app

Tags: html, ripple

Is it possible to invoke ripple emulator from a custom made web app (ASP.NET for instance)?

And when invoked can we just pass a local HDD file url to Ripple's invoked instance, [like](http://localhost:9090/sample/index.html) .

and then Ripple loads the same, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bet, just add a a querystring param: `enableripple=true`

That should work for you if you're using the chrome extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to dan & @Mark. I will check the same and get back. Thanks a lot for your time.